# Filterable widget issue with enter key

Tags: jquery-mobile

https://api.jquerymobile.com/filterable/

there seems to be a problem with the implementation of this widget in that, if you are typing into the text field, then press enter nothing happens, but then your next key press has no effect. eg:

1. focus on text field
2. press a ('a' appears in field)
3. press enter (no change)
4. ***press a (no change)***
5. press a ('aa' appears in field)

I have logged [an issue](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/8571), however doubt it will get attention in the short term. Anyone suggest a work around?

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/widgets/filterable.js#L210 to _prevent form submission_.

Comment: @Omar: BTW, are you aware of a (unofficial) clean, polished JQM 1.4.6 fork which contains all fixes expressed during the last two years? I'm unable to browse forks (too many to display).

Comment: @deblocker I have no idea to be honest. Have you tried the master branch? Or you could ask at jQuery forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least we can tell JQM to restore the `_preventKeyPress` flag by simulating another keypress:

```
$(document).on("keyup", ".ui-input-search>input", function(e) {
  var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which ? e.which : 0;
  if(key == 13) {
    $(this).trigger(jQuery.Event("keypress", {
      srcElement: this,
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true,
      which: 0,
      keyCode: 0,
      charCode: 0,
      target: this,
      currentTarget: this,
      eventPhase: 2, // AT TARGET
      type: "keypress",
      view: e.view,
      returnValue: true
    }));
  }
});
```

**EDIT:**

Just for the sake of completeness, here is the solution from [Omar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1771795/omar):

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/8571#issuecomment-300430818